# Unable to overwrite Bootstrap's default typography and headings CSS styles

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm having a real hard time overwriting some of Bootstrap's default CSS styles, more specifically typography and headings. Please take a look at the example below:

http://silvasonic.com/boostrap/index-001.html

The desired outcome should be something similar to the screenshot below:

http://silvasonic.com/boostrap/screen.png

For some reason the headers — and even the paragraph below that — are forced to bold, not matter what I do. The font has two weights (400, 700), but when I try to explicitly declare 700 for bold it gets some sort of double bold. I also understand that Bootstrap's default font-weight for headings is 500, but I should be able to overwrite it regardless.

I've tried a few different ideas — even including !important — but nothing seems to work.

Any / all feedback and help is very much appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: I experienced same kind of problem using custom fonts, it was because in imported the bold font and then also made the font-weight bold. When you import the bold font, you dont need to set the font-weight on bold.

Comment: Btw the link and the screenshot look the same here in Chrome

Comment: I opened the link on Chrome in a Mac and it was "over bold". When opening in Chrome in Linux, the two examples look the same. Could you include your computer print screen?

Comment: @joelharkes OK, let's say I declare the <h3> as font-weight: normal and let Bootstrap bold it by default, but how would I get the <h4> to **not** be bold (font-weight: 400)?

Comment: @Christina I just tried that and it doesn't change anything. Have a look: http://silvasonic.com/boostrap/index-001.html

Comment: The font ITSELF is bold. That means at font-weight: 400 or normal, it'll be bold! If you add font-weight: 700 or bold on it, it'll draw some extra boldness on top of the font. You can't make this face any less bold as it is.

Comment: It looks a lot better in Firefox but Chrome is thick like it always is. -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;

Comment: @Christina adding -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased; works! Check it out: http://silvasonic.com/boostrap/index-001.html

Comment: Yes, I know it always makes fonts look better in webkit

Answer (score 2):

As suggested by @Christina (see comments below) adding the `-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;` and '-moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;' properties fix the issue. The final CSS looks like this:

```
h3 {
font-family: 'Montserrat';
font-style: normal;
font-weight: 700;
font-size: 24px;
color: #333;
-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
-moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}

h4 {
font-family: 'Montserrat';
font-style: normal;
font-weight: 400;
font-size: 22px;
color: #777;
-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
-moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}
```

Thanks a lot for your help!